# Align shortcuts for MS Access .mdb forms

Tags: ms-access

Those of you below the age of 70 will not know the answer to this question! I learnt to program Access databases many years ago on Windows 95, long before the .accdb file type existed.  When designing forms there were some useful shortcuts for aligning controls, all beginning with Alt+O.
The ones I still remember are Alt+O S F "size to fit", Alt+O A R "align right", Alt+O A T "align top", Alt+O A L "align left" and Alt+O A B "align bottom".

There were also shortcuts for tweaking the horizontal and vertical spacing between controls, but unfortunately I can no longer remember them. If any kind soul knows what these other shortcuts are I'd be really interested in having my memory refreshed.

I tried searching the book I learned from "Building Applications with Microsoft Access for Windows 95" but couldn't find anything useful.  I've a feeling I learnt about these shortcuts from a different source.  I tried Google but got no relevant answers.

Comment: if you tap `ALT` - the ribbon will highlight the sequence to that if you know where it is in there

Comment: Not Alt but Ctrl - review https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-access-70a673e4-4f7b-4300-b8e5-3320fa6606e2#bkmk_workdesign

Comment: Also, https://documentation.help/MS-Office-Access-2003/AccessKeyboardShortcuts.htm

Answer (score 2):

Well, of course you can use the context menus, and thus this with the mouse:

[image]

Now, after selecting, you you CAN tap the alt-key, and the ribbon will display shortcuts, but they can be a good many key strokes.

One "quick" way is to use the built in windows shift-f10 to trigger the right click menu from the keyboard.

So, in place of above using the mouse, I could after selecting the text boxes hit shift-f10,

And now with the right click menu showing, I can hit the keys.

"a" for "align" and then "t" for top.
(so very few keystrokes)

And the longer way? Well, as noted, tapping the alt key will highlight (trigger) the context keys for the ribbon, but I find that requires quite a few keystrokes.

So, again, after highlighting the controls, I could tap alt.

You get this:

JA then SA then T

So, that is 6 keystrokes in total if you count the alt key. So, tapping alt key will highlight on the ribbon.

I find (and think) using the windows shift-f10 to trigger the right click menu is less keystrokes. Once done, then it is only 2 keystrokes. So, it looks really like the above right click with the mouse, but you 100% keyboard to open up the "right click context menu".

And a good number of keyboards STILL have a right click menu button - often a bit to the right of the space bar. So, in place of shift-f10, you can tap that shortcut menu key, and that's the fewest number of keystrokes, and you don't even have to use  (hold down) the shift key.

And note in that right click menu, then options for size (to fit).

However, the increase/decrase?

Don't remember the older keystrokes, so you probably have to tap the alt key, and using keystrokes from what the ribbon shows.

A good list of some shortcuts can be found here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-access-70a673e4-4f7b-4300-b8e5-3320fa6606e2#bkmk_workdesign

The fact of using mdb or accDB will of course not change your options much, and it is assumed you are using Access 2010 or later, but we actually don't know what version of Access you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was obvious nobody knew the answers I was looking for, I decided to experiment and discovered/remembered the following: for vertical spacing the first two keys are Alt+O V, and for horizontal spacing Alt+O Z. After this, you type E (to equalise), I (to increase) or D (to decrease).  I'm using Access 2010 and the main problem I have with it is that when editing a form it is essential to close the properties list before exiting design mode, otherwise you may have to wait 10 minutes while "Access is not responding".

I hope those of you who like to design their forms themselves (rather than relying on a wizard) find these commands as useful as I have done over the years.